# Display flex seems to be limiting the width of a component

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

Im making a reactjs app that so far got a header and another component. Initially it seems ok, but when i add a display: flex to their div, it seems to shorten the width of the header, as shows the images:[image: without flex]

[image: with flex]

How can i fix this?
This how the codes are looking like:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <main>
            <Header />
          </main>
          <Player />
        </div>  
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And the css:

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
:root{
  --red: #990606;
  --black: #222224;
  --white: #f0f0f0;
}

@media (max-width: 1080px){
  html{
    font-size: 93.75%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 720px){
  html{
    font-size: 87.5%;
  }
}

body{
  background-color: var(--white);
}

body, input, textarea, button{
  font: 500 1rem sans-serif;
}
h1{
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'VT323', monospace;
  font-weight: 500;
}
h2{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
button{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper{
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper.main{
  flex: 1;
}
```

Header jsx:

```
export function Header() {
    return(
        <header className="headerContainer">
         
        </header>
    )
}
```

Header CSS:

```
.headerContainer{
    background: var(--black);
    height: 6.5rem;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 2rem 4rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(grey);
}
```

Then the player code:

```
export function Player() {
    return(
        <div className="playerContainer">

        </div>  
    )
}
```

And its CSS:

```
.playerContainer{
    padding: 3rem 4rem;
    width: 26.5rem;
    height: 100vh;
    background: var(--red);
    color: var(--white);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: From your code it's not possible to reproduce the problem. Can you include the css and content for the header and player? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please share a code of your Header and Player component, So we can look into the issue in more detailed way and help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fixed with the flex grow or as i used in the code flex:1

```
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper.main{
  flex: 1;
}
```

What i was missing is that the main is not a class, so in the css i should be calling it like this:

```
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
}

.wrapper main{
  flex: 1;
}
```

With this adjustment its working fine

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove `display:flex` from your `.wrapper` class.

Here, is the demo link:  [Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/flexissue-forked-5w6v75?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqeq191k00062v6kdpw7m6oh%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqeq191k00022v6kaukgpuqu%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqeq191k00032v6k85hhmr57%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqeq191k00052v6kecr9741n%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clqeq191k00022v6kaukgpuqu%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqeq191k00012v6kfj232ilf%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqeq191k00022v6kaukgpuqu%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqeq191k00012v6kfj232ilf%2522%257D%252C%2522clqeq191k00052v6kecr9741n%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqeq191k00042v6kwu2chiv7%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqeq191k00052v6kecr9741n%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clqeq191k00042v6kwu2chiv7%2522%257D%252C%2522clqeq191k00032v6k85hhmr57%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clqeq191k00032v6k85hhmr57%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Screenshot:

[image]

Let me know, If you've any questions.

Comment: I needed the player to be in the right end of the page, but with the header in full size. Without the display flex the header doesnt fill the whole page just like my second printscreen shows

Answer (score 0):

Adding Wrapper CSS (flex-direction: column;)
Link : [Click...](https://playcode.io/1703075)

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
 }
```

Comment: I still wanted the player to be at the right end of the page, just like the second image, but with the header at full size

Comment: If You want player to be at the right end of the page you can Add one <div> for the wrapper class and add CSS (display:flex ,;justify-content: flex-end): https://playcode.io/1703075